# Compose, не работает animateItemPlacement в LazyColumn

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose, jetpack

у меня есть проблема с animateItemPlacement, он просто не работает(текст появляется без анимации). Код:

```
val laps = stopWatchViewModel.getLapsStates().collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(start = 52.dp, end = 52.dp)
) {
    items(items = laps.value, key = {lap -> lap.id}) { lap ->
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = 12.dp, bottom = 12.dp)
                .animateItemPlacement(
                    animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 250)
                ),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text(text = lap.lap, color = Color(0xff383838), fontSize = 20.sp)
            Text(text = lap.lapTime, color = Color(0xff808080), fontSize = 20.sp)
            Text(text = lap.totalTime, color = Color(0xfff7f7f7), fontSize = 20.sp)
        }
    }
}
```

В константу laps я передаю дата классы из базы данных, а потом собираю все это в состояние. В ключ я передаю конкретный айди каждого дата класса. Перепробовал очень многое: пробовал менять контейнер в котором лежит **Row** на **Card** и **Box**, менял ключ на **key = { it.id }**, **key = {lap -> lap.id}**, всё это не сработало. Я просто не понимаю в чем проблема. Уже спрашивал на англоязычном stackoverflow, там не помогли(тоже не понимают в чем проблема). Репозиторий с проектом: https://github.com/BRBXGIT/AlarmApp, папка Screens, файл StopWatchScreen. Заранее спасибо